# Implementing strictly lower bound in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, binary-search

I have come up with this solution to implement strictly lower bound in a sorted array:

```
long lowerBound(long key, long size, long *a){
    long low = 0, high = size, mid;
    if(a[low] >= key){
        return -1;
    }
    while(low < high){
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if(a[mid] >= key){
            high = mid - 1;
        } else{
            low = mid;
        }
    }
    return low;
}
```

But this does not seem to work. It fails at some test cases. For example:

A[7] = {0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 10}

key = 4

It enters an infinite loop.

Here is the test run:

After first iteration:
low = 3, high = 7, mid = 3

After second iteration:
low = 3, high = 4, mid = 5

After third iteration:
low = 3, high = 4, mid = 3.
Then it get stuck.

Can anyone point me in right direction. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might have noticed there is no tag for "C/C++". Simple reason is: C and C++ are different languages. Please pick the one you use and remove the wrong tag. Also see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why down vote? I have searched and could not find perfect solution

Comment: @RawN: So much about "C/C++" ...

Comment: It is not strictly lower bound.

Comment: Some simple debugging may help: throw in a `printf("low = %ld, high = %ld\n", low, high);` at the start of the while loop.  Then walk through the code yourself for the values that it gets stuck at to see why it stops progressing.

Comment: Why did you choose this implementation? Are you sure that this implementation provides you better performances than a linear search? Of course, it depends on the nature of the data stored in the array.

Comment: @acornagl, Binary search is quite efficient because it does at most ceil(log2(N)) comparisons (e.g. <= 10 comparisons for an array with 1000 elements).

Comment: @ikegami, exactly! I completely agree with you. Is the author of the question conscious of the binary search benefits or performances? A vote for you ;)

Comment: If `size` is the number of elements in the array, you should set `high` to `size - 1`. Otherwise you could return an index beyond the end of the array. That could be what you want, just make sure you test to make sure the return from the function isn't too big.

Comment: I deliberately chose this implementation because of efficiency of binary search.

Comment: What do you mean with "strictly"?To me the description of the C++ method looks like "strictly".

Comment: It returns less than or **equal to** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets "stuck" because when your `low` equals `high - 1`, `mid` becomes `low`: `(low+low+1)/2 == low`, then `a[mid] >= key` is `false` and `mid` sets to `low` again. You need to set `low` to `mid + 1` if `a[mid] < key` and set `high` to `mid` otherwise. Then you will find *the first occurrence of key or, if there is no element, equal to key, the first occurrence of the element that is greater than key, and, if all the elements are less than key, you will get the initial value of high*.

**UPD:** And, since it's **binary search,** you will **always** get `low == high - 1`. Keep it in mind next time!

**UPD2:** And one more thing! It would be better to use `mid = low+((high-low)/2)`, because this prevents some overflow errors.

Comment: But doing that will not get me strict lower bound.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3165873 What do you mean saying "strict lower bound"?

Comment: In above example for key = 5 or 4, it should return lower bound index as 3 (considering 0 based indexing).

Comment: @user3165873 When I run it like this: `printf( "%d\r\n", lowerBound( 4, 7, A ) );`, it prints `4`

Comment: Exactly, it should print 3.

Comment: @user3165873 Perhaps you just need to return `low-1`

Comment: @user3165873 Yeah, with `return low-1`, you get `3` with `key == 4 or 5`

Comment: @user3165873 Then I misunderstood the concept of strict lower bounds. Try this: `if( a[low] == key ) return low; else return low-1;`

Comment: But a[low] > key i.e. 5 > 4 in our case. So this seems incorrect.

Comment: @user3165873 I said above: make it `return low-1` if you haven't found any occurrences of `key`

Comment: for lowerBound(4, 7, A) it gave 4, and A[4] = 5. And 5 is not less than or equal to 4.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @user3165873 So, does this fit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Take this example:

```
low = 3
high = 4
```

So what will your code do?

```
while(low < high){         // True as 3 is less than 4
    mid = (low+high)/2;    // (3+4)/2 --> mid = 3
    if(a[mid] >= key){     // a[3] is 3. And 3 isn't greater or equal 4 so this is false
        high = mid - 1;
    } else{                // So you take the else part

        low = mid;         // low is assigned 3. So you are back
                           // where you started and have an endless loop
    }
```

You need to make sure that assignments to `low` and `high` isn't just assigning the value they already have.

For instance:

```
else {
    if (low == mid) return low;
    low = mid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If every element of the array was unique, you could use the following:

```
long binsearch(long *a, long size, long key) {
    long lo = 0;
    long hi = size-1;

    if (hi == -1)
       return -1;

    while (1) {
       long mid = ( lo + hi ) / 2;
       if (a[mid] == key)
          return mid;

       if (a[mid] < key) {
          hi = mid - 1;
          if (lo > hi)
             return ~mid;
       } else {
          lo = mid + 1;
          if (lo > hi)
             return ~lo;
       }
    }
}
```

But your array can have duplicates, and you want to find the first one, so we need to tweak what is considered a match.

```
long binsearch_first(long *a, long size, long key) {
    long lo = 0;
    long hi = size-1;

    if (hi == -1)
       return -1;

    while (1) {
       long mid = ( lo + hi ) / 2;
       if (a[mid] == key && ( mid == 0 || a[mid-1] != key ))
          return mid;

       if (a[mid] <= key) {
          hi = mid - 1;
          if (lo > hi)
             return ~mid;
       } else {
          lo = mid + 1;
          if (lo > hi)
             return ~lo;
       }
    }
}
```

You may have noticed the peculiar return value. It has the advantage of returning where the `key` would have been found if it wasn't. This tells you where you would insert `key` if you wanted to add it to the array.

```
long i = binsearch_first(a, a_size, key);
if (i >= 0) {
   printf("The first %ld was found at index %ld.\n", $key, i);
} else {
   printf("%ld wasn't found. It would have been found at index %ld.", $key, ~i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You start with `high = size`, so the upper bound is out of range and should stay that way, that is, it is never a solution.

So two errors follow: the end condition, and the setting of the new `high` value.

The end condition should be

```
while (high - low > 1)
```

after which the solution will be `low`. And the setting of the new `high` value should be

```
if(a[mid] > key){               // change from >=
    high = mid;                 // mid is not valid
}
```